# Suggestion on merging these two questions

Tags: discussion

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/340481/65969) question was asked about installing flash.

It was correctly flagged as a duplicate to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/56446/65969) question.

While the answer to the duplicate does not impart any new info that was not mentioned in the answers to the original question, it does provide 2 screenshot to help explain how to do it using the Software Center.

As we know, alot of users on AU are newbies and likely converts(or at least potential converts) from Windows so are more comfortable with GUI's than command line.  Any help we can give will increase the chance that the newbies will stay long enough to get used to Ubuntu and maybe leave Windows completely.

That being said I think that answers like the one that was given on the Dup question should be encouraged, and the people that give these kind of answers should be encouraged/rewarded by upvotes.  This is the reason that I am requesting/suggesting that the two be merged instead of the dup just being closed.

I do not want to take away from [jrg's](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg) answer to the original question, it is correct and accepted, but, as I understand it, the dup will not affect the originals answers in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion about GUI answers vs Commandline answers has been discussed several times in [Use the GUI as much as possible in answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6721/use-the-gui-as-much-as-possible-in-answers) and [Should answers have terminal or GUI instructions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/60/should-answers-have-terminal-or-gui-instructions), do I'm not going to address that.

However the questions have been merged.

Comment: Thanks, I was not trying to discuss CLI vs GUI, I was only trying to explain my reasoning in why I thought the question should be merged, and as that was a major part of my reasoning, I was expanding on it a little.  Thanks for the link to the questions however, it contained some interesting info.

Comment: @TrailRider Ah, OK. Well we pretty much merge any time a dupe has good answers, so that was fine :)